# Do something if a program is running

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, process

Is there something you can type into terminal so that it will run a command if a certain program is running?  For example, `if <Libre office is running> then sudo pkill <Libre ofice>`.

Edit 1: So what I want to do is make an if statement in terminal that runs if a program is running and if it is not it does nothing, or does something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "what I want to do is make an if statement in terminal that runs if a
>   program is running and if it is not it does nothing, or does something
>   else"

To determine if a program is running given its name, use `pgrep`.  To dosomething if LibreOffice's word processor is running:

```
pgrep soffice.bin >/dev/null && do_something
```

Similarly, to do something if LibreOffice's word processor is *not* running:

```
pgrep soffice.bin >/dev/null || do_something
```

Further, you can use these two in combination:

```
pgrep soffice.bin && do_one_thing || do_another
```

Or, if things get more complicated, use an `if` statement:

```
if pgrep soffice.bin
then
    # command is running
    do_one_thing
    do_one_thing2
else
    # command is not running
    do_another
    do_another2
fi
```

The above work because `pgrep`, just like `grep`, sets a useful exit code.  If a process is found, it returns with an exit code of zero (which the shell interprets as logical true).  If not, it returns with one (the shell interprets any non-zero exit code to mean false).

To find out all the programs that are currently running (and hence what name to use as the argument to `pgrep`), run `ps ax`

Comment: Was just about to answer almost the same thing. You might want to add the combination of the two into one: `pgrep soffice && do_one_thing || do_another`